# Hosting a web app on one server and rendering on another

Tags: web, hosting

Scenario: The login page for a host of web applications lives on an internally hosted server. When this server gets rebooted we need this login page to remain accessible, even if it just displays a friendly message.

The thought I am having is rendering this login page on a different app hosted in the cloud. When our server then gets rebooted the cloud hosted app will instead render a different message.

Is this even a viable option?
What are the pitfalls of this approach?
Are there any cleaner and better alternatives? (And "host the login page in the cloud" has already been considered but I'm looking for alternatives to that as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is totally possible, what your describing is a [reverse proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19146-01/821-1828/6nmpm01bn/) or load balancer have a look at [configuring apache as a reverse proxy server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)

Comment: Thanks Eru. How would the reverse proxy handle the situation where the remote server was unavailable and we wanted to display some form of custom message instead?